# Organize ggplots from a for loop into a single array

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I successfully created plots of 18 variables by months in the year (no January data) using a for loop, but I can only get them to output 1-by-1.  I simply want to output them as a single image (page) with 6 rows and 3 columns.  I'm want to do this from within the base-R and ggplot universes.  Below is the code for the successful plots.  How do I arrange into the array?

```
batspp<-names(Monthly_means[7:24])

for(i in batspp){
  plt<-ggplot(Monthly_means, aes_string(x="Month", y=i))+geom_col() + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"), label=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"))
  print(plt)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(gridExtra)
batspp<-names(Monthly_means[7:24])
plt = list()
for(i in batspp){plt[[i]]<-ggplot(Monthly_means, aes_string(x="Month", y=i))+geom_col() + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"), label=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12")) }
do.call("grid.arrange",c(plt, nrow=6, ncol=3))
```

This should work

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly.  I had tried this before and thought it failed because nothing displayed in the plot window of RStudio. Now I see that I have to use the Zoom button to display the full plot. I tried harder because I knew you must be correct.